# Slack Sensu alert getting cut off

Tags: alert, monitoring, sensu, slack-api

I am attempting to get some custom info in my Sensu Slack alerts via [this plugin](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/handlers/notification/slack.rb) but it seems that adding the `message_prefix` is causing weirdness in the slack message formatting.

For example, I would like the entire message with extra message prefix stuff to be posted but the last line is getting cut off and the "Show more..." appears on the same line as the last part of the message

The message formats correctly if I don't include `message_prefix`, but doesn't include the additional info so I would like to find out a way to get everything working with the prefix.

[image]

Here is an example of what I would like the message to look like by default.

[image]

Does anybody know what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I work for Slack and there's a few things that could be causing this. If you could write into https://slack.com/help/contact and give your permission to look at your team's Sensu messages we'll take look at the messages the plugin is posting. With this information we'll be able quickly narrow down the cause and hopefully fix this issue.

Afterwards, with your permission of course, we're happy to share what we learn back here for future Slack and Sensu users.

Comment: Wow, awesome.  Message sent!